# How to trigger an alarm on the Telegram message?

Tags: iphone, shortcut, alarm

I am looking for a way to implement next feature: I want to find a way on how to trigger any kind (not only from the built-in application) of alarm after the Telegram message.

For example, I am sleeping and in the middle of the night someone texts me. There is a high change that the sound of the notification (with `Do Not Disturb` mode turned off) won't wake me up, but long loud alarm would be albe to do that.

I have checked the Shortcuts application and there is nothing can be done about it. There is similar functionality, but for the Messages application, not third-party (the Telegram in this case).

From what I have seen, the Telegram bot could be the potential solution for this problem, but it cannot read private messages.

I am looking for ANY kind of solution. It can be application or the way I can implement it programatically. I have experience and I will be able to implement something like that but right now I am looking just for ways of the implementation.